# Trouble Creating JSON with MVC3 (asp.net) using static Json class (system.web.helpers.json)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having trouble creating the following JSON using uisng the C# MVC3 system.web.helpers.json namespace.  Here is what I am trying to form:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"", "Data": [ { "Id":167 } ] }
```

What I have tried is this (with no success)

```
var x = Json(
            new {Id = result.SponsorListId});

        return Json(new
                        {
                            success,
                            msg = success ? "" : "sponsorListResult Passed Into Update as null",
                            Data = new List<Json>() {x}

                        }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

I've tried lots of other things also, but no point in listing all my failures.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all the Json() method does is serialize the object you send it. When you send it a List you are sending it a JsonResponse which isn't what you are intending. What you should do is:

```
   return Json(new
                    {
                        success,
                        msg = success ? "" : "sponsorListResult Passed Into Update as null",
                        Data = new []{ new { Id: result.SponsorListId } }
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

Which should serialize out to where you want it to be.

Comment: hmm.  the syntax:  Data = new []{ { Id: result.SponsorListId } } doesn't compile.  It's not obvious to me how to fix it.

Comment: `new[] { new { Id: result.SponsorListId } }` notice the second `new` keyword

Comment: Sorry, missed that, fixed. SO edtor really needs a c# compiler attached to kill these issues . . .